# ng-show and ng-if is not working on ionic ion-item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

What I am trying to do is, when the user successfully logged in, the app will display different menu based on role of user.

**Login Controller**

```
//some relevant codes
user = res.data;         
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
console.log(user[0].role)

if(user[0].role == 1 ){
    $scope.isAdmin = true;
    $scope.isEmployee = false;
    $state.go("app.home");    
}else if (user[0].role == 2){
    $scope.isEmployee = true;
    $scope.isAdmin = false;
    $state.go("app.home");
}
```

In these controller, I am trying to set the response data to a `user` using `localStorage` to use it for later purposes. If the user entered valid login credentials, app will determine its specific role and redirect to `home`.

**Home Controller**

```
function authenticate() {
var user =localStorage.getItem("user");
user = JSON.parse(user);
      if(user[0].role == 1){
        console.log('admin');
        $scope.isAdmin = true;
        $scope.isEmployee = false;
        console.log($scope.isAdmin);
      }else if (user[0].role == 2){
        console.log('employee');
          $scope.isEmployee = true;
          $scope.isAdmin = false;
          console.log($scope.isAdmin);
      }
}

authenticate();
```

**HTML View**

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">RMS</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-show="isAdmin" class="item item-icon-left" menu-close href="#/app/home">
        <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
      Admin Home
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item ng-if="isEmployee" class="item item-icon-left" menu-close href="#/app/home">
      <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
      Employee Home
  </ion-item>
```

In this `view`, `ng-show` and `ng-if` is not working as I expected. Im having a tough time in this simple showing of certain `ion-item` depends on the logged-in user.

Comment: are you sure your `isAdmin` and `isEmployee` evaluating to true/false correctly ?

Comment: @Rahul yes, I think it is. Cause I tried to `console.log` the `isAdmin` and it returning a expected value which is `true` and currently logged in as `admin`.

Comment: Can you show what output you are getting in console? I mean what is console.log printing?

Comment: @SiddheshPhatak, In `homecontroller` i added a `console.log(isAdmin)` to see if it evaluating a correct value, and found out that it is. When logged in as `admin` the `console.log(isAdmin)` logs `true` in console.

Comment: @Marksmanship do one thing; bind `{{isAdmin}}` and `{{isEmployee}}` in the HTML. check what u getting there in HTML. ? and in both location use `ng-show` only

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. I get it. I put the code in the wrong controller, thats why it will not show what ever happens. My bad. 
But, some problem showed, When I logged out and logged in as new user eg. logged out as `admin` then logged in as `employee`, the `admin` menu still showing and the `employee` menu does not.

Comment: post your logged out function code please

Comment: You may need to reset both isAdmin and isEmployee in logout function

Comment: okay thanks. how i can reset it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155392/discussion-between-marksmanship-and-rahul).

Comment: @Marksmanship shall post this as answer then.please accept if it solves ur issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly see if you are assigning `isAdmin` and `isEmployee` in right controller. 
Check if `{{isAdmin}}` and `{{isEmployee}}` evaluates to true/false by binding them in HTML.

For second problem try to clear localstorage and assign `$scope.isEmployee = false;` and `$scope.isAdmin = false;` again in logout function.